I want to use a DPDT switch to supply power to an electrical heater and also to my welder using one 30amp 2 pole breaker. How do I wire the switch
I want to use a DPDT switch to power an electric heater and then  switch to power my welder when needed using the same 2 pole 30 amp breaker. The power must go to the switch first correct and then switch to either device. how do I wire the switch ( using 10/3 with g)

This feels more like a DIY question.
